# Создание анимации

Tags: анимация, jquery, html, javascript

Создал сайт, хочу сделать анимацию как на картинке:

Переход из меню
http://f.mypage.ru/68bed5aa59bf4662999baff27e0f6110_eacb991345f13a67c3c98b284fcfcb0d.jpg

Переход из раздела
http://f.mypage.ru/24d9933474635cb5b2aa1fc383034042_c6ce0760f2d0bee31e36f80f6d627d87.jpg

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Comment: А Вы смотрели как это сделано на сайте, где Вы увидели такую анимацию

Comment: Опишите как оно должно работать, только словами, а то из картинки не совсем понятно.